# Check if group contains element before forming it in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Below is sample of my Dataset;

```
name       status
google    Active
Facebook  Active
Tex       Active
Tex       WUP
Yout      Active
```

I am trying to create two DataFrames based on the Count of names(=1 and >1)

Code written :

```
#single occurance DatFrame
df_single=pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("name") if len(g) == 1)
#Multi Occurance DataFrame
df_multi=pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("name") if len(g) > 1)
```

The Problem is when i have data like this

```
name       status
google    Active
Facebook  Active
Tex       Active

df_multi=pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("name") if len(g) > 1) fails
```

This fails saying no data to concat. Can i check if group exist before concat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use another solution - [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`, so possible filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.groupby("name")['name'].transform('size')
print (s)
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    1
Name: name, dtype: int64

df_single = df[s == 1]
df_multi = df[s > 1]
```

If want only filter by duplicates simplier is create boolean mask by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
m = df['name'].duplicated(keep=False)
print (m)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: name, dtype: bool

df_single = df[~m]
df_multi = df[m]
```

---

```
print (df_single)
       name  status
0    google  Active
1  Facebook  Active
4      Yout  Active

print (df_multi)

  name  status
2  Tex  Active
3  Tex     WUP
```

Comment: second answer is impressive +1

Comment: @MohamedThasinah - Thank you!

Comment: Excellent @jezrael. You always give answers in 2 mins. It works. Thanks a lot